# Capture output of a fork without printing to console

Tags: javascript, node.js

Im trying to capture the console.log of a fork instead of letting it output to the console. I recognize you can do stdout('something') in the child and capture that in the host process, but I want to make console.log have the same behavior.

Eg:

Host

```
require('child_process').fork('child.js');

//capture console.log of child..
```

Child

```
//natively capture this in Host
console.log('foo');
```

Answer (score 1):

Provide an options object with an stdio property as the final argument to the fork call.

See here: 
https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options

Comment: But how would I mute the console output?

Comment: That is explained in the documentation I linked to. Do you want to do something other than what is described there? If so, please explain how it would be different.